# How do I get to the common tab in run configurations in Eclipse using SWTBot?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swtbot

We're writing some tests using SWTBot, and we need to change some things in the common tab of the run configurations during the test. Any idea on how to navigate there?

Thanks,
Oren

Answer (score 0):

Try `bot.cTabItem(index).activate();`

Answer (score 0):

it works for me by using the Keyboard func (shortcut: ALT+C):

```
KeyboardFactory.getAWTKeyboard().pressShortcut(Keystrokes.ALT,KeyStroke.getInstance(0, 'C'));
bot.sleep(3000);
```